# How to use Yield in a nested loop while iterating a Tree

Tags: php

In php I want to iterate a tree of object with `children` properties.
I tried this approach but this seems to iterate only on the first tree level objects. How to nest the yields ?

```
    public function iterateTree(array $children, ?ExtendedItemCategory $parent): iterable {
       /** @var ExtendedItemCategory $child */
       foreach ($children as $child) {
           $child->setParent($parent);

           if ($child->countChildren() > 0) {
                $this->iterateTree($child->getChildren(), $parent);
           }
           yield $child;
      }
   }

    // how i test
    ...
    $categoriesTree = ...

    $iterable = $this->iterateTree($categoriesTree, null);
    foreach ($iterable as $iter)
    {
        var_dump($iter->getCode());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `yield from` in the iterateTree inner call:

```
if ($child->countChildren() > 0) {
   yield from $this->iterateTree($child->getChildren(), $parent);
...
```